# Returning an iterator from a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I have two simple container: one that stores a pointer and another one that stores a flat_set of pointers. In order to be able to use for(auto ...) on both of them (or stl algorithms), I would like to add begin/end to them. For the one with the flat_set, I just have to return the iterators of the flat_set but how can I do the same for the container that just holds a pointer?

I would like to avoid having to create a complete iterator class just for that... Basically, I would like to do something like that:

```
class Container
{
    ...
    Iterator begin() { return the_pointer; }
    Iterator end() { return the_pointer+1; }
    private:
    int* the_pointer;
}
```

But I don't know which signature Iterator must have.

Thanks !

Comment: *But I don't know which signature Iterator must have.* What do you mean by that?

Comment: just include `typedef int* iterator; typedef const int* const_iterator;` in you class definition and return the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your container holds sequence of pointers (they stored in memory like normal array), then you can simply return pointer from your class

```
int * begin();
int * end();
```

It is because for ( ... : ... ) syntax is expanded to something like:

```
for ( auto begin = container.begin(), end = container.end();
      begin != end; ++begin )
 // ...
```

Comment: ok, but when I do that why do I got int instead of int*? I mean I have to write for(int& i : container) instead of for(int* i : container).

Comment: @user52730: if you want to iterate over pointers, and not values they pointing to, you need to define `begin()` and `end()` function as: `int ** begin()` and `int ** end()`.

Comment: Aaah yes, almost there :) It works for begin but how to do the end since this is illegal: int** end() { return &(the_pointer+1); } ?

Comment: Just to be sure, I did this for begin: int** begin(){return &the_pointer;} , is it ok?

Comment: @user52730: If you want to store only one pointer at time, you should not implement `begin()`/`end()` methods because it doesn't make sense. You should make something like get method (if you want to access it), or maybe use [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: @user52730: But if you want to shot yourself into foot, here is your arsenal: http://ideone.com/j9vwFg

Comment: @Andzej: It works, thanks! Now you are probably right that this is not a good idea. I just wanted to be able to use any STL algo or range-for loops on both containers. But maybe it is just non sense.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers to object types are valid iterator types, so you can just return a pointer. In fact `std::array<T,N>` has `T*` as its iterator type.

Answer (score 1):

C pointers are legal iterators. [Here](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterator-define.html) you can check an useful guide on them with a section on how to implement iterators from pointers. Basically you need to implement `begin()` and `end()` returning *first* and *last* valid pointers.

Comment: Thanks for this guide!

Comment: Just to clarify, `end()` should actually return the pointer _after_ the last valid pointer.